# Why won't my third party javascripts like KnockoutJS pass Windows App Certification Kit?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I am aware of the MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction problem when it comes to DOM manipulation in jQuery, but even a modified version of jQuery [link here](http://www.incloud.de/2012/08/windows-8-using-jquery-for-app-development/) fails verification with the Windows store.

It seems the pattern here is that all my Nuget pulled scripts fails verification. Anybody figures why?

```
Error Found: The bytecode generation test detected the following errors:

File \\?\C:\Program Files\...\Scripts\require.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems.
File \\?\C:\Program Files\...\Scripts\r.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems.
File \\?\C:\Program Files\...\Scripts\knockout-2.2.0.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems.
File \\?\C:\Program Files\...\Scripts\knockout-2.2.0.debug.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems.
File \\?\C:\Program Files\...\Scripts\knockout.mapping-latest.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems.
File \\?\C:\Program Files\...\Scripts\knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems.
File \\?\C:\Program Files\...\Scripts\jquery-1.8.3.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try saving your files with the UTF8 byte-order mark (BOM) encoding. I had a similar issue and that solved the issue.

> in VS > File Menu > Advanced Save Options > select UTF-8 with
>   signature Codepage 65001

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh849088.aspx
Not specific to your issue, but bytecode caching.

HTH